# On applying custom sort-sorttype in jqgrid, I need to avoid sorting on full records and sort only on records that is present in current page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sorting, jqgrid

In my model i have given the custom sort as below.This sorts on all the records that is bind to grid rather than sorting only for the rows that is shown in the current page.

```
sorttype: function (cell, obj) {
                                if (cell.match(/<a/))                                
                                    return $(cell).text();                                
                                return cell;
                            },
```

Example: My grid is holding around 100 rows and in each page only 10 rows are displayed. when I sort on any column it will consider all the 100 rows and sort them. However this had to sort only for the 10 rows of the current page.

I am very new to jqGrid and facing lot of issues. Can any please help me on this

Comment: You need to only be capturing those 10 rows rather than capturing all of the rows that you have.  Custom paging is what you are after.

Comment: oh ok. If I fetch the 10 records at first time then I next icon will get disabled to fetch next 10 records

Comment: @oleg I have seen your reputation and u understand my problem from scratch. Can seek some help from you :)